# Object's container field is empty after move and erase

Tags: c++, vector, move-semantics, erase

I have two vectors and I want to move an object from one to the other, before I move it I make a pointer to the object. But when I erase the index in first vector then the container within the object is empty if I access it through the pointer. It's difficult to describe, some code will explain it better:

## Word.h

```
class Word
{
public:
    Word(string text);
    ~Word();

    string text;
};
```

## Card.h

```
class Card
{
public: 
    Card(vector<Word>& words);
    ~Card();

    vector<Word> words;
};
```

## main()

```
vector<Word> words {
    Word("dog"),
    Word("cat"),
    Word("horse")
};

Card card(words);

vector<Card> deck1;
vector<Card> deck2;

deck1.push_back(move(card));

Card* p = &deck1[0];
deck2.push_back(move(deck1[0]));
cout << p->words.size() << endl; // 3

deck1.erase(deck1.begin());

cout << p->words.size() << endl; // 0 <-- Why is size() 0 here?

p = &deck2[0];
cout << deck2[0].words.size() << endl; // 3 <-- and 3 here
cout << p->words.size() << endl; // <-- and 3 here! 

getchar();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moves have no effect because `Card` has no move constructor or move assignment operator. The vectors `deck1` and `deck2` contain copies of whatever is pushed into them.

But the problem (or at least, one problem) is that you invalidate `p` when you erase from `deck1`. De-referencing `p` is undefined behaviour (UB).

```
deck1.push_back(move(card));
Card* p = &deck1[0];
....
deck1.erase(deck1.begin()); // p invalidated
....
cout << p->words.size() << endl; // UB, anything can happen

p = &deck2[0];
cout << deck2[0].words.size() << endl;
cout << p->words.size() << endl; // No problem, p points to deck2[0]
```

Comment: I thought I was starting to understand move semantics, but I understand where I went wrong, thanks!